# What is algorithm of converting 8 bit binary to 16 bit bcd?

Tags: assembly, binary, avr, bcd, atmega16

What is algorithm of converting 8 bit binary to 16 bit BCD?

for example:

how can i do this?

1111 1111 (binary) *->* 0000 0010 0101 0101

Answer (score 2):

The fastest computational method would be a modification of the "bin2BCD8" routine as described in [AVR204](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0938.pdf). Subtract 100 until the number is less than 100, incrementing a single byte counter (in an even register) each time. Then do the same for 10, with the counter in the register after the hundreds counter. Use `SWAP` to move the tens counter to the high nibble, add the units remainder, and return the 16-bit register value.

Comment: That is not the fastest, be careful stating such things ;) A lookup table is probably faster, but costs memory.

Comment: @Jester: Fair enough. Amended.

Comment: Not even that is true. The atmega16 has a hardware multiplier, so I bet you can do better than looping (on average). Well, maybe not, but it's a close call. Would have to compare actual implementations :)

Answer (score 0):

You can jump to `find_hundreds` (after clearing CL and CH) to convert a single 8-bit value stored in FL (AVR 8-bit instruction set).

```
.DEF FL = r17
.DEF FH = r18
.DEF CL = r19
.DEF CH = r20

; input:
;     FH:FL registers holding hex value
; output:
;     FH:FL registers holding converted BCD value
hex_to_bcd:
    ldi CL, 0
    ldi CH, 0
find_thousands:
    subi FL, low(1000)
    sbci FH, high(1000)
    brmi thousands_found ; branch if minus
    subi CH, -16
    rjmp find_thousands;
thousands_found:
    subi FL, low(-1000)
    sbci FH, high(-1000)
find_hundreds:
    subi FL, low(100)
    sbci FH, high(100)
    brmi hundreds_found 
    subi CH, -1
    rjmp find_hundreds;
hundreds_found:
    subi FL, low(-100)
    sbci FH, high(-100)
find_tens:
    subi FL, low(10)
    sbci FH, high(10)
    brmi tens_found      
    subi CL, -16
    rjmp find_tens;
tens_found:
    subi FL, low(-10)
    sbci FH, high(-10)
find_ones:
    subi FL, low(1)
    sbci FH, high(1)
    brmi ones_found 
    subi CL, -1
    rjmp find_ones;
ones_found:
    subi FL, low(-1)
    sbci FH, high(-1)
    mov FL, CL
    mov FH, CH
```

Comment: Once you've reduce the number below 100, can't you skip the high-half `sbci`?  The high half of every number below 128 is 0, so `sbci r18, 0` with no borrow is just a waste of instructions.  (So is `subi FL, -1` after `ones_found:`, right before you overwrite FL and FH.)  Also, can't you arrange things (including initial counter values) so you can `subi CH, -16` *before* FL, so you can use the opposite of `brmi` as the loop branch, instead of needing a separate `rjmp`.  Like maybe `ldi CL, 0xEF`, if I have that right: the high nibble will get 2 extra increments, one from carry-out in the low.